# BuddyPress Xprofile fields to display on “wordpress user edit admin panel”

Tags: wordpress, field, admin, buddypress

I am using supermassive-BuddyPress theme with wordpress 3.8 and BuddyPress 1.9.I have added one additional field(Mci Number) to my registration form.
I want this xprofile field values in Wordpress user edit admin panel.

website:http://harsh031.0fees.net/register/

I tried below query and added to function.php. but ended up with nothing.Can you please help.?

```
<?php 
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'showmy_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'showmy_extra_profile_fields' );
function showmy_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label>Mci Number</label></th>
            <td>
                <?php 
                if( function_exists( 'xprofile_get_field_data' ) ) {
                    $xprofile_value = xprofile_get_field_data('Mci Number', $user->ID );
                }
                else {
                    $xprofile_value = '';
                }
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="Mci Number" id="Mci Number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $xprofile_value ); ?>" class="regular-text" readonly />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code to add the MCI Number in user profile from admin side:

```
function addd_new_fields($data) {
    if(!empty($data)) {
        $mciNumbar= get_user_meta($data->data->ID, 'mcinumber', true);
        ?>
        <h3>Register Additional Fields</h3>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="mcinumber">MCI Numbar</label></th>
                <td><input type="text" id="mcinumber" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo ($mciNumbar) ? $mciNumbar: ''; ?>" name="mcinumber"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('edit_user_profile','addd_new_fields',0,1);

function save_new_fields_value($user_id) {
    if (!empty($user_id)) {
        update_user_meta($user_id,'mcinumber', $_POST['mcinumber']);
    }
}
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'save_new_fields_value',0,1);
```

Comment: Hi Chirag, I pasted the code in themes function.php file and added a filed named  "MCI Number" in base profile field. However I updated this field form buddypress profile. But I cant see any field in  admin panel(Users->all users) with MCI Number information. Please help suggest.

Comment: Please check it on the any other users profile(Not Admin) from admin side...There you can see at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks For your valuable input. I can see this additional field on users profile. Editing and updating this field from admin panel is working fine. But this field is not being updated on admin side, when a user enter its value from buddypress edit profile menu(editing or updating the field is only being saved on users buddypress profile which is visible to users only on buddypress profile). Can you please suggest how we can synchronize these two.

Comment: Here we have added above code for the wordpress(Not Buddypress) custom fields. If you want to sync fields then you will edit the above code. Currently mcinuber is come from post meta and update post meta. There you can change the code for get the xprofile field data and update the data.

Comment: You have to use below code:
Get xprofile data: xprofile_get_field_data( 'mcinumber', $user_id )
Update xprofile data:  xprofile_set_field_data('mcinumber', $user_id,  $newvalue);

Comment: Thanks chirag..
I need to work on the same.. Will update you if I find some Issue.. :P